# Kotlin Decorators/Annotations for Function to reduce Boilerplate

Tags: kotlin

I am writing a library to interact with a third party RESTful API. I'm using Retrofit to do that. Each API endpoint has a defined HTTP code that indicates success (some are 200, some are 201, some are 204, etc.).

Rather than having the base that Retrofit generates from be:

```
UsersService {
    @GET("some/path")
    fun getPath(): Call<SomeObject>
}
```

and then in another class

```
fun getPath(): SomeObject {
    val result = myUsersService.getPath().execute()
    if(result.code()!=201) throw SomeException("")
    return result.body()!!
}
```

I would really like to do something in my Retrofit "definition" file like

```
UsersService {
    @SuccessCode(201)
    @GET("some/path")
    fun getPath(): Call<T>
}
```

which would generate whatever the Retrofit code generates, but then effectively wrap it in a function like

```
fun someGeneratedFunction(fn: ()->Call<T>): T {
    val result = fn.execute()
    if(result.code() != 201) throw SomeException("")
    return result
}
```

In Python these are function decorators. Reading over annotations, they appear to be something for classes, not functions. Is there a way to do this with Kotlin?

This reduces boilerplate, which could be done in other ways I know, but I like that it makes the UsersService file more self-documenting than it already is. I have looked over the Retrofit guide, but I can't find anything suggesting they've already got an annotation like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For retrofit the functionality to do this already exists, take a look at [this retrofit example](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/samples/src/main/java/com/example/retrofit/AnnotatedConverters.java).

For the behavior you want:

1. Use `retrofit.(nextRequestBodyConverter|nextResponseBodyConverter)` to retrieve the actual converter for the method type.
2. Check if the annotation is present in `annotations`

   1. If present, wrap the converter and check the response code, throwing an error on failure.
   2. If absent, just return the original converter and don't change its behavior.